# vim c++11 constexpr highlight

Tags: c++11, vim

The new c++ keyword constexpr is not highlighted by vim. I have tried plugins like this one:
http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4617

It worked very well for everything else except constexpr.

Does anyone know how I can turn syntax highlight on for constexpr in my cpp.vim (or by using other methods)?

Comment: Just add that keyword to whatever syntax script you use and send a patch to its maintainer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In vim 7.4 (and probably earlier, but 7.4 is what I have installed), `constexpr` should be set up by the standard `cpp.vim` file, which should be a part of your installation.

It is, however, guarded in a test for the `cpp_no_cpp11` variable:

```
" C++ 11 extensions
if !exists("cpp_no_cpp11")
  syn keyword cppType       override final
  syn keyword cppExceptions noexcept
  syn keyword cppStorageClass   constexpr decltype
  syn keyword cppConstant   nullptr
endif
```

You can `:echo exists("cpp_no_cpp11")`; if the result is 1, that would explain why you don't see the highlighting (you'll have to diagnose your configuration to see why it's getting set, though).

Alternatively you can go for a brute force method and put

```
syn keyword cppStorageClass constexpr
```

in your `.vimrc` (along with whatever other else you want; seems like you'll also be missing `decltype`, et cetera). Or you can put the command in a script file that you load via `autogroup` or using the "after" directory (like the plugin you linked) if you want to be gentler in your approach.

(Note that the plugin you linked doesn't attempt to add C++11 keyword highlighting at all, at least not for `constexpr`. It's mostly concerned with functions and type names.)

Comment: thank you for the answer, it turned out the highlighting was not on because I failed to load the correct colorscheme(I tried to load the colorscheme before its vundle line, and put the block in a try catch so no error was detected..), the default scheme was loaded and it happened to use no special color for c++11 keywords. Thanks a lot for the tips you give, they are very useful to know!